# Get current fullPage.js options/settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Wondering if there is a way to get current fullPage.js options/settings. I need to know whether `fitToSection` and `autoScrolling` are true or false. I see there is a way to set using `$.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection()` and `$.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling()`, but do we have the opposite like `$.fn.fullpage.getFitToSection()` or `$.fn.fullpage.getAutoScrolling()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop. They are not accessible. But as you are the one setting them up, you can keep tack of it in your own code.

```
var fitToSection = false;

$('#fullpage').fullPage({
    fitToSection: fitToSection
});

$('#demo').click(function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(false);

    //keeping track of it in my side
    fitToSection = false;
});

$('#demo2').click(function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(true);

    //keeping track of it in my side
    fitToSection = true;
});
```

This way you'll always be able to access your global `fitToSection`.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro for your prompt answer. Based on your example, I assume fullPage.js plugin itself won't change `fitToSection` and `autoScrolling` settings automatically in any circumstances. Let me know if I understood wrong.

Comment: It will change internally `autoScrolling` when using `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight`. But you can always know when this happens by using the callback `afterResponsive`. Regarding `fitToSection`, that will also change to `false` on responsive.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @Alvaro. Very helpful.